# unsaved domain class with one to many returns child objects in random order

Tags: validation, grails, constraints, children

So here is the situation:

I have a class. For examples sake:

```
    class Author {
       String name

       static hasMany = [books: Book]
       static mapping = {
         books cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
       }
    }

    class Book {
       String text

       static belongsTo = [author: Author]

       static constraints = {
         text minSize: 500
       }
   }
```

Now, I create a form for this one to many and when I attempt to validate, the person did not enter at least 500 characters for text, so I return the object back to the form.

The problem is THE CHILD OBJECTS ARE NOT RETURNED IN THE ORDER I CREATED THEM!!! How do you all validate child objects of a domain class that has never been saved?!?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
class Author {
   String name
   ArrayList<Book> books = []
   static hasMany = [books: Book]
   static mapping = {
     books cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
   }
}
```

If not works I think you have to order by some field

You can specify the sort order this way

```
class Author {
   String name

   static hasMany = [books: Book]
   static mapping = {
     books cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
     books sort: 'id', order: 'desc'
   }

}
```

Comment: Ill try the first one, however the sort option on the field only applies to saved objects - I've been down that road.

Comment: This actually caused a different error - java.io.NotSerializableException

Comment: For clarification I changed ArrayList<Book> books = [] to : List books. This is now finicky on how you save your objects - I was getting "flush during cascade is dangerous" while not doing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

By default, `hasMany` uses a `Set` to store related objects, and a `Set` has no notion of order per-say. If order matters to your application, I would recommend using a `List` instead.

Comment: Just out of curiosity..why is Set the default? When would that be more beneficial comparative to a List?

Comment: Set is the default because usually in associations you only want to associate to a single instance of a Foo with a Bar, so the Set implies uniqueness. A List, since it has an order to it, also requires that order to be persisted, so you essentially need an "ordinal" on your association, so it's messier than just an associative table on the relational db side of the persistence mapping.